# How to collect 2 coroutine Flow<T>?

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I have 2 `SharedFlow<T>`s and I want to take actions on their latest emissions. There is a `combine` operator which has the similar effect but I do not think it is supposed to be used that way since it is not a terminal operator. Please help!

```
val flow1 = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
val flow2 = MutableSharedFlow<Double>()
flow1.collect(flow2) { a, b ->
    //do something with a and b
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think you need a `zip` operator: https://blog.mindorks.com/kotlin-flow-zip-operator-parallel-multiple-network-calls

Comment: Like i said, operators such as zip and combine are not terminal operator. I would like to avoid any intermediate step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to collect, the combined flows, like:

```
val flow1 = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
val flow2 = MutableSharedFlow<Double>()
flow1.combine(flow2) { a, b ->
    //do something with a and b
   a to b // for ex
}.collect{
 
}
```

See [combine](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html) for more information

Comment: Thanks, this is what i initially thought. Maybe it is the only way to go.